# calling an interactive bash script over ssh

Tags: bash, scripting, ssh, scp, ssh-tunnel

I'm writing a "tool" - a couple of bash scripts - that automate the installation and configuration on each server in a cluster.

The "tool" runs from a primary server. It tars and distributes it's self (via SCP) to every other server and untars the copies via "batch" SSH.

During set-up the tool issues remote commands such as the following from the primary server: `echo './run_audit.sh' | ssh host4 'bash -s'`. The approach works in many cases, except when there's interactive behavior since standard input is already in use.

Is there a way to run remote bash scripts interactively over SSH?

As a starting point, consider the following case: `echo 'read -p "enter name:" name; echo "your name is $name"' | ssh host4 'bash -s'`

In the case above the prompt never happens, how do I work around that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at puppet or similar configuration managers. And don't do distributed configuration interactively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run the command directly, like so:

```
ssh -t host4 bash ./run_audit.sh
```

For an encore, modify the shell script so it reads options from the command line or a configuration file instead of from stdin (or in preference to stdin).

I second Dennis Williamson's suggestion to look into puppet/etc instead.

Comment: I didn't realize at first, but this works! Using passwordless authentication (DSA), I SCP the scripts to all servers and execute them remotely. The solution is both distributed and interactive just how I wanted at first. I just introduced configuration to substitute prompts per Dennis' comment, but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want to look into [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Comment: As a band-aid for the immediate problem, yes. The proper fix is to not require interactive configuration.

Comment: Sure - but that's not always a luxury available (in this case it's a batch script, but in the more general case it might be a different executable which isn't easily modified).

Answer (score 0):

Do not pipe commands via stdin to ssh, but copy shell script to remote machine:

```
scp ./run_audit.sh host4:
```

and then:

```
ssh host4 run_audit.sh
```

For cluster deployments I'm using Fabric... it runs on top of SSH protocol, no daemons needed. It's easy as writing fabfile.py:

```
from fabric.api import run

def host_type():
    run('uname -s')
```

and then:

```
$ fab -H localhost,linuxbox host_type
[localhost] run: uname -s
[localhost] out: Darwin
[linuxbox] run: uname -s
[linuxbox] out: Linux

Done.
Disconnecting from localhost... done.
Disconnecting from linuxbox... done.
```

Of course it can do more... including interactive commands, and relays on ~/.ssh directory files for SSH. More at [fabfile.org](http://fabfile.org). For sure you will forget bash for such tasks. ;-)